# In UWP, how would I get the instance of a Grid, that's in a Flyout, that is itself in a ResourceDictionary?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I have a UWP app which will be deployed to a device with a screen. The device is running Windows 10 IoT Core.

I want to have some form of an alert system, and because I cannot use the UWP `ToastNotification`, I decided to create my own. I created a `UserControl` for the notification and that works fine. I show the control dynamically in a `Flyout`, and that works fine to a point.

Flyout is in a ResourceDictionary and looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:HCI">

    <Flyout x:Key="ToastNotificationFlyout" x:Name="ToastFlyout" 
            ShowMode="Transient" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False">
        <Grid x:Name="ToastContainer" />
    </Flyout>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have a static class...

```
static class Globals
{
    public static Flyout GlobalFlyout;
}
```

...which allows me to reference the Flyout from any class in my code (Pages loaded dynamically through a content Frame).

In my MainPage instance, I create the reference like this:

```
Globals.GlobalFlyout = (Flyout)Application.Current.Resources["ToastNotificationFlyout"];
```

I can then reference the `Flyout` in C#, but I cannot seem to get a reference to the `Grid`.
Flyout doesn't contain a `.FindName()` method, and using `VisualTreeHelper` throws a Catastrophic Exception (explained in another SO issue by another user).
I have also tried various invocations of `.FindChild()` and `.FindControl()`, that I've found here and in other communities, but none work for this case.

The content of the Flyout is straightforward, mimicking the look of a regular Win10 toast notification.

Any thoughts on how to reference the `Grid` in the `Flyout`, so that I can add an instance of the notification control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Grid` is actually stored under the [`Flyout.Content` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.content):

```
var grid = (Grid)Globals.GlobalFlyout.Content;
```

When you put a direct child inside a `Flyout` XAML interprets it as the `Content`. This is done under the hood using the [`ContentPropertyAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.contentpropertyattribute).

Comment: Thank you so much, that one was driving me crazy ;0)